# Database is locked when launching multiple instances on development server

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm trying to run 2 instances of GAE (through the launcher) that runs php55.
The first one wraps an API and has a DB connection. The second one makes curl requests on the first one.
If I run either the first one or the second one, I have an error in the logs when accessing the URL :

> OperationalError: database is locked

Any thoughts?

Comment: I doubt the dev environment supports more than one app. make one use the published other.

Comment: By DB I assume you mean MySQL database running locally?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/

Comment: @ZigMandel well, I don't want to publish any of them right now because I'm still working on both.

Comment: @Mars by DB connection, I mean a MySQL locally but on GAE, it's Cloud SQL. But I don't think it's related. I assume it says the database is locked regarding the datastore. Maybe it's because the development server requires a datastore and when launching multiple instances of different applications, one cannot use the same than the other.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood Sorry but I don't get your point :/

Comment: I see. Do you have the full log from the console? Also are you trying to run two copies of the same app? Or two different apps?

Comment: @Mars Here's the log : http://pastebin.com/UqHhyz4M It's two different apps

Comment: Have you tried specifying a different --storage_path for each app? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/tools/devserver#PHP_Command-line_arguments

Comment: @Mars Well, I tried to setup a datastore_path but not a storage_path for one of the two (for the second one, I didn't change anything) but it's doing the same... Should I try with storage_path ? I felt like the issue is coming from the datastore_path :/

Comment: The error suggests that it's a clash in --log_path so setting --storage_path should solve the problem as well. Otherwise you can also use a different application id for each instance.

Comment: @Mars Oh my bad... I thought I set two different app id but I did not... Thank you for your time!